# A × SILENT + LISTEN = ANAGRAM

Tags: alphametic

<sub>*An anagram is direct word switch or word play, the result of rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase, using all the original letters exactly once*</sub>

---

Solve this alphametic

$$\text{A} \times \text{SILENT} + \text{LISTEN} = \text{ANAGRAM}$$

There is only 1 solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's

> $2*809154+908415=2526723$

First off

> $A$ had to be a small number, and it obviously wasn't 1, so trying two was an obvious solution. This allows us to then get rid of the multiplication step and convert to a much easier addition alphametic:
>
> ```
> SILENT
> SILENT +
> LISTEN +
> _________
> 2N2GR2M
> ```

,

> Then $S+S+L$ has to have a value which is over 20, I don't really have a logical explanation for this bit except I tried a few things and one of the things I tried was $S=8$ and $L=9$. This gives:
>
> ```
> 8I9ENT
> 8I9ENT+
> 9I8TEN+
> ________
> 2N2GR2M
> ```

From this

> $I$ has to be 0, because the catty from the thousands column is 2 and the result of the tens of thousands is also 2. Hence $3I$ ha to equal 0 so $I = 0$
>
> ```
> 809ENT
> 809ENT+
> 908TEN+
> _______
> 2N2GR2M
> ```

Next

> It is logical to work out $N$, and it has to be $N=5$
>
> ```
> 809E5T
> 809E5T+
> 908TE5+
> _______
> 252GR2M
> ```

I'll have to finish this explanation later...

Answer (score 6):

before answering this I want to say that I was a bit lucky on finding the solution.  But here is my reasoning anyway.

Solutions:

> $2 * 809154 +908415 = 2526723$

Since $A$ is the most used letter and the multiplier I tried to take it step by step.
I skipped $A=1$ because if it was 1 you would have made the puzzle without the multiplier :).

Going to $A = 2$

Now the alphametic becomes:

> ```
>    SILENT + 
>    SILENT + 
>    LISTEN = 
>  ------
>   2N2GR2M
> ```

Because $A=2$

> It means that the carriage from S+S+L+(other carriage) should be 2. This means that S and L have large values.

This is where I got lucky.

> I tried with $S=8$ and $L=9$

Now we have

> ```
>    8I9ENT + 
>    8I9ENT + 
>    9I8TEN = 
>  ------
>   2N2GR2M
> ```

Immediately we see that

> The carriage from the thousands column is $2$ and the result on the tens of thousands is $2$. This means that $3*I$ ends with $0$.  THis can only result in $I=0$

Writing it again with the new values:

> ```
>    809ENT + 
>    809ENT + 
>    908TEN = 
>  ------
>   2N2GR2M
> ```

We get instantly the value of $N$ form here because it's not affected by the rest of the digits.

> $N = (8+8+9)\%10 = 5$
>
> ```
>    809E5T + 
>    809E5T + 
>    908TE5 = 
>  ------
>   252GR2M
> ```

We can drop the first 2 digits because they are all determined and we can reduce this to

> ```
>    9E5T + 
>    9E5T + 
>    8TE5 = 
>  ------
>   2GR2M
> ```

We see that T has to ...

> ...be bigger than 2 because otherwise we get $E = 2 = A$
>  Trying with $T=3$ we get $M = 1$ and $E = 1$...wrong.
>  Going with $T=4$
>
> ```
>    9E54 + 
>    9E54 + 
>    8415 = 
>  ------
>   2GR23
> ```
>
> So we have $M=3$ and $E = 1$
>
> ```
>    9154 + 
>    9154 + 
>    8415 = 
>  ------
>   2GR23
> ```

We can simply add the numbers to find $G$ and $R$. we get

> $G=6$ $R=7$

Since there is only one solution I stopped looking and felt happy about myself.